# State or event not getting changed in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have defined one abstract stateless widget following way

```
abstract class BaseStatelessWidget<T extends Bloc> extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (shouldHideStatusBar) {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    }

    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) {
            BaseBloc baseBloc = getIt<BaseBloc>();
            baseBloc.add(BaseEvent.networkListeningInitiated());
            return baseBloc;
          },
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => getImplementedBloc(context),
        ),
      ],
      child: BlocListener<BaseBloc, BaseState>(
        listener: _handleState,
        child: buildScreen(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool get shouldHideStatusBar => false;

  _handleState(BuildContext context, BaseState state) {
    // here different state will be managed
  }


  Widget buildScreen(BuildContext context);

  T getImplementedBloc(BuildContext context);
}
```

Another stateless widget SigninPage extending it following way

```
class SigninPage extends BaseStatelessWidget<SigninBloc> {
  @override
  Widget buildScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SigninForm(),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get shouldHideStatusBar => true;

  @override
  SigninBloc getImplementedBloc(BuildContext context) {
    return getIt<SigninBloc>();
  }
}
```

For sake of this question i removed redundant codes from SingInForm class here is the code :

```
class SigninForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PrimaryButton(
      btnText: getString(context, StringKeys.signin),
      onButtonClick: () => onSignin(context),
    );
  }

  onSignin(BuildContext context) {
    context.bloc<BaseBloc>().add(BaseEvent.changeLoaderStatus(visible: true)); => this is not working I tried to check if it is null. this is not null
    context.bloc<SigninBloc>().add(SigninEvent.loginWithEmailPassword()); => this is working fine
  }
}
```

This is my BaseBloc class defined. Neither mapEventToState() method nor onTransition() method getting called.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:refyne_app/domain/core/i_network_aware_facade.dart';
import 'package:refyne_app/domain/core/logger.dart';
import 'package:refyne_app/infrastructure/core/api_service/connectivity_status.dart';

part 'base_event.dart';
part 'base_state.dart';
part 'base_bloc.freezed.dart';

@injectable
class BaseBloc extends Bloc<BaseEvent, BaseState> {
  INetworkAwareFacade _networkHandlerFacade;

  BaseBloc(this._networkHandlerFacade)
      : super(BaseState.initial(
          isLoaderVisible: false,
        ));

  @override
  Stream<BaseState> mapEventToState(
    BaseEvent event,
  ) async* {
    yield* event.map(
      networkListeningInitiated: (_) => _handleNetworkChange(),  <== This one is causing the issue, if i remove this method. It works fine.
      networkListeningStopped: (_) async* {},
      changeLoaderStatus: (ChangeLoaderStatus value) async* {
        logger.d('from bloc loader called with $value');
        yield state.copyWith(isLoaderVisible: value.visible);
      },
    );
  }

  Stream<BaseState> _handleNetworkChange() async* {
    await for (ConnectivityResult result
        in _networkHandlerFacade.onConnectionChange()) { <== onConnectionChange will give you a stream
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        yield state.copyWith(
            connectionStatus: ConnectionStatus(
          type: ConnectionType.NONE,
          isworking: false,
        ));
      } else {
        bool isworking = await _networkHandlerFacade.checkConnection();
        ConnectionType type = result == ConnectivityResult.mobile
            ? ConnectionType.MOBILE
            : ConnectionType.WIFI;

        yield state.copyWith(
          connectionStatus: ConnectionStatus(type: type, isworking: isworking),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void onError(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    if (error is Exception) {
      _handleException(error);
    } else {
      super.onError(error, stackTrace);
      // TODO:: handle this exception scenario
    }
  }

  _handleException(Exception e) {
    print(e);
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Transition<BaseEvent, BaseState> transition) {
    logger.d('from base bloc ${transition.event}');
    logger.d('from base bloc ${transition.currentState}');
    logger.d('from base bloc ${transition.nextState}');
    super.onTransition(transition);
  }
}
```

i am trying to access base bloc defined in BaseStatelessWidget class. My defined child bloc is working fine and it is also sending events as well. My problem is i am not able to change the state of parent bloc. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? any help will be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: try using flutter_bloc package it's more easier to use and provides you DI as well, so you don't need to use get_it.

Comment: i am using flutter_bloc, but only for listening to state change not for object management. Do you think it can be the issue?

Comment: Flutter_bloc provides BlocProvider and from that you can use BlocBuilder in order to see the changes in the states. you don't need get_it and other stuffs if you are using flutter_bloc package.

Comment: that is true, i am using flutter_bloc to listening for the changes in state. But this issue is something else, I am not even able to change the state in the first place.

Comment: As from your code I can see that you are using bloc listener for state changes, which is wrong, you need to use blocbuilder for your scenario. Bloc listener can only be used for showing snackbar,alert dialog, page navigation,etc only.

Comment: let me try that way

Comment: No luck bro, I tried using BlocConsumer instead of builder, coz i needed listener as well. But it is not working.

Comment: You can check my repo on how to use blocbuilder with bloclistener.  Check this out. https://github.com/jaydangar/CookingApp/blob/master/lib/pages/home_page.dart

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for the whole one day, Now I understand why it was happening. I was handling stream directly inside mapEventToState method. When i moved stream handling from mapEventToState to constructor, then it is working fine.
Hope it will help someone...

See this example for more info.

[Flutter Bloc with Stream](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_bloc_with_stream)

Comment: I see your code and I'm glad it's working, but I don't understand why you have to build your own subscription object or stream when you inherit from Bloc ... can you explain this please??